# Determining number of required plaintext pairs for differential cryptanalysis

Tags: cryptanalysis, differential-analysis, spn

When carrying differential analysis of a SPN network, how can one determine the number of required plaintext for the attack to be successful with high probability?

Comment: You might want first to compute the probability of your trails and select the one with the highest chances.

Comment: @Biv I've already done that. Just not sure how to proceed from this point.

Comment: let us assume that you have a probability $1/2^p$, then you will need at least $2^p$ pair to exhibit this characteristic once (in average). By multiplying this number by... 1000 you should be able to have the number of pair that you need.

Comment: For DES, they need $2^{20} \approx 1000000$ pairs while the probability of the characteristic is $1/55000$.

Comment: @Biv
I am facing the same question as SpiderRico. Hope I can get an answer here:

Let us assume I have a trail with probability 0.0264. This is as fraction 7/1024. 1024 = 2^10 => I need at least 1024 Pairs, right? Do you may be have some literature about that? May be a paper? I need something to read about that, but did not find anything except this post here.

Comment: @chris000r https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/464.pdf and the presentation I gave at AsiaCrypt 2018 : https://benoit.viguier.nl/files/MiniMorus-Asiacrypt.pdf